# overridePendingTransition() is not work perfectly when its started from service

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, service

Activity class code:

```
public class Content extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.animation_layout);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_out_bounce);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        }, animation.getDuration());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.zoom_out_bounce);
    }
}
```

Above Activty Called on `Service`

```
public class LockScreenService extends Service {


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int i) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
        registerReceiver(new LockScreenReceiver(), intentFilter);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);

        //Set up a receiver to listen for the Intents in this Service
        receiver = new LockScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Content.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
       //deviceManger.lockNow();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

above all code Work perfect but problem is ,

[[image: when my content activity start time animation can not work perfectly]

can some one give me answer of my question?

1.can i start activity from service ?

2.can i set animation when activity started from service?

Comment: post your service class code..

Comment: see.. my edited my question...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can start `activity` from `service`

`android.app.Service` is descendant of `android.app.Context` so you can use `startActivity` directly.

try this code to start activity:

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(this, Content.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

you can also setanimation when activity started from service

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

write this after

```
startActivity(i)
```

Comment: yes...i same included this code on my project but  still its  not work

Comment: just at this time my question is ...how to solve above error ..who are display on imgae...(how to animate current screen from service ?)

Comment: @KalsariyaDevindra call startActivity in onStartCommand method instead...onStartCommand() is called whenever a client calls startService().